# Meaning of constant $\{N_{i}\}$

Tags: notation

I have a doubt concerning the notation $\{N_{i}\}$. In in the derivation at constant $\{N_{i}\}$  of a number (like $\left(\frac{dA}{dB}\right)_{\{N_{i}\}}$) does this notation mean that the total number of the ensemble is kept constant, or that the number of of each individual N ($N_{1}$, $N_{2}$, $N_{3}$... ) is kept constant.

I am assuming it is the later, but I can't convince myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some context for this? It is really unclear what you are referring to. In what branch of mathematics or what book or what website do you find this notation?

Comment: Derivation of a thermodynamic potential. Many examples like here in the section "the equation of states" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I found the answer while looking for an example for Paul Sinclair. It does mean each specie is at constant number. Sorry if the question is unclear and thank you.

Comment: The important thing is that you have the answer, and it's always better when you figure out the answer yourself, anyway. Just remember that the meaning of many notations differ between fields of study, and often between particular books in that field. So when asking about meanings of notations, it is best to give information about where you found the notation.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for my future questions, thank you.